# Are these web application requirements even realistic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

Our customer wants an ASP.NET web application with user management and different roles, but has some very strange conditions:

- The application should work from a browser, the users should be able to login and do stuff according to their given rights. (so far so easy)
- The typical scenario would be that many people with different user privileges work from the same machine, same windows account and same browser. (in turns) Still they should not be able to have any access to data that other users have seen or do anything out of their account.

For me this probably means:

- I can't use any type of caching.
- I can't use any type of cookies.
- I can't do anything important over GET parameters.
- I have to be very careful about sessions.

Still I don't see how I could (with certainty) prevent browser side caching. We tried to explain that this kind of stuff is what windows accounts are for, but he seems to be pretty consistent that he wants to keep it all on one account.

Is this a realistic requirement and what do I have to keep in mind when realising an application with such security requirements?

This has never been an issue with applications I developed before, so I'm not really sure how to handle this.

Comment: How are the requirements any different from multiple people logging into gmail from an internet cafe?  Just make sure the users log out and use HTTPS.

Comment: They probably are not. Is https enough to prevent possible browser side caching?

Comment: @atticae - HTTPS will cause all browser data to be discarded at the end of a session, regardless of the caching settings. However you still need to end the session, which means that your users will have to be careful to always log off.

Comment: And you shouldn't ever alter data over a GET, as browsers assume that all GET requests are repeatable. If you're changing data POST from a form or using Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are these web application requirements even realistic?

Yes they are. Online Banking applications typically do this by abandoning their session after a period of inactivity. Also if you close the browser the session should be abandoned. A manual log out is a good idea.

Some other points

> I can't use any type of caching.

Not on the web browswer no, but session caching is fine.

> I can't use any type of cookies.

Except for session cookies no

> I can't do anything important over GET parameters.

Yep

> I have to be very careful about sessions.

This is probably always a good idea.

Comment: I would also like to add that based on these requirements, when a logout is performed the session needs to be abandoned else session hijacking is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you use sessions (provided by default with ASP.Net) you should be fine. Just make sure that the users log out or enforce a reasonably short auto-log-out.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not planning on using Windows Integrated authentication, then the requirements aren't so bad.  If you're using Windows authentication, then no, you can't meet requirement #2 realistically, without adding usability issues.

However, even if you're using Forms authentication, you need to ensure that users log out of your web site (or close all browser windows) when they are done.  Failure to log out can (and likely will) give the next person to simply continue browsing and see all the data the previous person saved.

You will probably need to explain this to your business users so they understand it, because unless you do, they might try to blame you for their failure to log out.  Many end users have no idea how such things work, and it's usually up to us to explain to them in non-technical (or at least comprehensible) terms what the limitations of technology are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these requirements are very realistic. In fact you should take them into consideration for every ASP.NET application.
You need to make sure you have proper session and cookie management, session caching and make use of Membership and Role providers(custom or built in) in your application.
Of course the user that had previously been logged in would need to be logged out, or you can force the log out.